# Transform column values into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's assume I have the following table:

```sql
-- 1. Create table 'Store'
CREATE TABLE Store 
(
    Customer int,
    Product varchar(50)
);
    
-- 2. Add values to the table:
INSERT INTO Store
VALUES (1, 'Carrot'),
       (1, 'Milk'),
       (1, 'Bread'),
       (1, 'Eggs'),
       (2, 'Water'),
       (2, 'Juice'),
       (2, 'Wine'),
       (2, 'Coffee'),
       (3, 'Chicken'),
       (3, 'Tea');
```

I want to change the table in order to see all customer's products in one row like shown below:

| Customer | Products |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Carrot,Milk,Bread,Eggs |
| 2 | Water,Juice,Wine,Coffee |
| 3 | Chicken,Tea |

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @nbk I'm assuming the OP isn't stuck on SQL Server 2005... They added `STRING_AGG` to SQL Server 2017, which is now fairly established so I assume the OP can use it.

Comment: @Dai all what you posted is there in the canonical answer, so this is a duplicate

Comment: Yeah, but I was feeling bored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    s.Customer,
    STRING_AGG( s.Product, ','  ) AS "Products"
FROM
    Store AS s
GROUP BY
    s.Customer
ORDER BY
    s.Customer;
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]